# How do I make a plugin show only on one page in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, buddypress

I installed "buddypress albums" to my website. I also had "Buddypress Activity Plus" (of which I deactivated because those two are not connected.)

Users on my website still want the "Buddypress activity Plus" plugin for the groups but it is not needed for my main "activity" page.

How do I get the "Buddypress activity plus" plugin to show on the groups but not my main activity page?

thanks

Comment: You can use short codes to place the plugin anywhere you want.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a buddypress you have to assign the groups functionnality to a page. You can still use the same if(is_page(pageid)) method to display your plugin. However since you're talking about users you may have to specify in the php that the user have to be logged if buddypress don't work around it itself.

This may help to check if the user is logged : 
http://pastebin.com/rgJ6BQc8